# Mostrar correctamente Panel o formulario personalizado al activar evento OnClick

Tags: c#, windows-forms

**Trasnfondo:**

Estoy generando una aplicación de tipo Windows Form cuya funcionalidad principal es consultar información a través de un servicio web.

El diseño del formulario *(controles)* consisten en:

- (1) TextBox
- (1) Button

Debido a la latencia de la respuesta, es necesario informar al usuario que *una vez oprimido el botón para activar la solicitud* al sistema tomará un tiempo en responder. Según las pruebas que he realizado, la solicitud tarda entre 3 a 5 segundos *(incluso, un poco mas)*.

Para ello, pretendo usar alguna de las siguientes opciones:

1. *MessageBox personalizado* para que *una vez completada la solicitud* se cierre automáticamente.
2. *Panel oculto* que se activará (Visible = True) antes de ejecutar la solicitud; cuando la solicitud se complete, vuelve a su estado anterior (Visible = False).
3. *Segundo formulario (llamado **FrmMsg**)* que se invoca *tal y como se muestra en este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2dwQWvlJO4)*.

El *segundo formulario **FrmMsg*** tiene los siguentes controles:

- PictureBox (con un archivo .GIF)
- Label "con texto establecido por defecto".
- Button *(para cerrar el formulario)*.
- Propiedad `FormBorderStyle = None`.

El diseño de las soluciones alternativas que he descrito luce así:

[image: Diseño del mensaje de prueba.]

**Problema:**

He optado *(por cuestiones de tiempo destinado al desarrollo)* usar la opción 2 o 3 citada anteriormente; sin embargo, al activar el botón para hacer la solicitud, se presentan los siguientes problemas:

- Con el *Panel oculto*, éste tarda en visualizarse. La solicitud tarda entre 3-5 segundos en completarse y considero que *(a pesar de que la propiedad `Visible` cambia de `False` a `True`)* la interfaz del programa está congelada y por lo tanto, ningún cambio es visible (hasta que la solicitud se complete).
- Con el *Segundo formulario **FrmMsg***, éste se invoca, pero los controles que posee este formulario lucen traslúcidos = los espacios destinados para los controles están vacíos.

He intentado agregar la siguiente línea de código en diferentes partes de la lógica:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500); // 1.5 segundos.
PanelOculto.Visible = true;
```

Pero la visualización (ya sea del Panel o del Segundo formulario **FrmMsg**) sigue sin generar el resultado esperado.

**¿Qué se puede hacer para visualizar el Panel y/o el segundo formulario correctamente?**

Comment: Deberías ejecutar la tarea pesada en un segundo hilo de tal forma que la interfaz gráfica sigua respondiendo durante el proceso.

Comment: La solicitud para consumir el servicio es muy directa; he visto algunos ejemplos de cómo se puede hacer esto, pero nada que haya podido replicar. Por desgracia no puedo compartir el código fuente en este caso, pero si usted desea sugerir en una respuesta una manera de generar este segundo hilo, les estaré agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**>>la interfaz del programa está congelada y por lo tanto, ningún cambio es visible**

Esto sucede porque el thread de la UI queda bloqueado, podrias intercalar la linea

[Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx)()

para que devuelva el control a la UI y asi se actualice el panel.

Otra opcion seria que uses el

[BackGroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

con esto podrias lanzar el proceso en otro hilo y asi no bloquear la UI y se muestre el movimiento del panel. Usarias el evento [RunWorkerCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) para pasar a invisible el panel.

**>>la imagen que contiene el control PictureBox es un .gif, el cual no se está "animando"**

Ese es un problema comun, simplemente carga el gif desde codigo usando

```
Picturebox1.Image = Image.FromFile("ruta gif");
```

podrias poner este codigo en el load del form