# C#, 3 Capas, Windows Forms - Mejorar Rendimiento

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms

necesito llenar un datagridview con mas de 7,000 registros que los obtengo a traves de un metodo que me devuelve una lista genérica de objetos. Mi problema es que cuando le asigno al datagriview.DataSource = PosicionesLN.ObtenerTodos(); a través del método load del Form, se friza y bloquea la aplicación completa por mas o menos 30 segundos y después de eso, se llena el grid y todo bien!.

**1- Como implementar una barra de progreso utilizando async y await?, para informarle al usuario el progreso de esa tarea.**

Nota: Utilizo programación en 3 capas, el Formulario esta en un proyecto que pertenece a la capa de presentación, el cual se comunica a la capa de acceso a datos a través de la capa de negocio. (Visual Studio 2015, C# y MySql).

[image: Arquitectura 3 capas]

```
// Proyecto Entidades:
public sealed class Posicion
{
    public int IdPosicion { get; set; }
    public Fila Fila { get; set; }
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public string NombreCompleto => string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0} - {1}", Fila.NombreCompleto, Numero);

}

// Proyecto AccesoDatos: PosicionAD.cs  
public static List<Posicion> ObtenerTodos()
{
        var lista = new List<Posicion>();
        const string sql = @"spu_posicion_obtenertodos";

        using (var lector = helper.ExecuteReader(CommandType.StoredProcedure, sql))
        {
            while (lector.Read())
            {
                lista.Add(CargarPosicion(lector));
            }
            return lista;
        }
}

private static Posicion CargarPosicion(IDataReader dr)
{

        var ordinalIdPosicion = dr.GetOrdinal("idposicion");
        var ordinalIdFila = dr.GetOrdinal("id_Fila");
        var ordinalNumero = dr.GetOrdinal("numero");


        var colCount = dr.FieldCount;
        var values = new object[colCount];

        var objPosicion = new Posicion();
        dr.GetValues(values);

        objPosicion.IdPosicion = Convert.ToInt32(values[ordinalIdPosicion]);
        objPosicion.Fila = FilaAD.ObtenerPorId(Convert.ToInt32(values[ordinalIdFila]));
        objPosicion.Numero = Convert.ToInt32(values[ordinalNumero]);

        return objPosicion;
}


// Proyecto LogicaNegocio: PosicionLN.cs    
public static List<Posicion> ObtenerTodos()
{
    return PosicionAD.ObtenerTodos();
}

// Proyecto Presentacion: FrmPosicion.cs
private void FrmPosicion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dgvDatosPosicion.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgvDatosPosicion.DataSource = PosicionLN.ObtenerTodos();


}
```

Comment: También te puede interesar mi [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/17171/78). Básicamente, una alternativa a la respuesta dada por Karloz Rivas es: crear un nuevo formulario que contenga un gif de "cargando..:" y éste lo invocas antes de llenar los datos en tu formulario principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No utilices el BackgroundWorker a menos que estés anclado a versiones antiguas de .Net framework.

Lo recomendable desde .Net 4.5 es utilizar async y await:

```
public static async Task<List<Posicion>> ObtenerTodos()
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
        var lista = new List<Posicion>();
        const string sql = @"spu_posicion_obtenertodos";

        using (var lector = helper.ExecuteReader(CommandType.StoredProcedure, sql))
        {
            while (lector.Read())
            {
                lista.Add(CargarPosicion(lector));
            }
            return lista;
        }
    });
}

public static async Task<List<Posicion>> ObtenerTodos()
{
    return await PosicionAD.ObtenerTodos();
}


private async void FrmPosicion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvDatosPosicion.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgvDatosPosicion.DataSource = await PosicionLN.ObtenerTodos();
}
```

Veo muchisima gente recomendando métodos antiguos cuando desde hace bastante se utilizan async y await.

Answer (score 0):

Usted necesita implementar un BackgroundWorker, de esta manera podrá realizar el cargado de datos desde una tarea diferente a la que se ejecuta cuando el formulario esta cargando y evitara que la interfaz de usuario se detenga mientra realiza su proceso:

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Eventos
     bw.DoWork += Bw_DoWork;
     bw.ProgressChanged += Bw_ProgressChanged;
     bw.RunWorkerCompleted += Bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

    //Inicializa el backgroundworker
    if (!bw.IsBusy)
         bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   //Ejecuta el proceso
   dgvDatosPosicion.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
   dgvDatosPosicion.DataSource = PosicionLN.ObtenerTodos();

   //Notifica el porcentaje de proceso
   bw.ReportProgress(/*####*/);
}

private void Bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
   //mostrar este valor en un ProgressBar
   var percent = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void Bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Write("Completado!");
}
```

Comment: Hola, 
La solución es buena, pero dentro del metodo Dw_DoWork no deberías acceder a componentes que estan en el hilo que maneja la capa visual, 
en el metodo do_work debererías rellenar una lista y en el metodo runworkercompleted pasarle la lista al datagrid

Answer (score 0):

En varios de mis proyectos, tengo que hacer la carga de varios datagrids con cantidades de rows bastantes grandes.
Lo que suelo hacer es cargar todos los datos desde el init de la aplicacion con metodos sync y await asi que cuando cargan los views de los grids ya tenemos los datos mas rapido porque ya estan en memoria.

Espero te ayude este comentario.

Saludos.